# Write a Java program that asks the user if he/she likes Java programming

Tags: java

Homework assignment:

> Write a Java program that asks the user if he/she likes Java
>   programming.
>
> If the user answers yes, then it displays a congratulating message
>   (use your imagination),and terminates.
>
> Now, if the user answers no, then the fun starts.
>
> – The program should ask Are you sure you don’t like Java
>   programming?.
>
> ∗ If the user answers no, then it should display Hope you’ll get to
>   like it soon...
>
> ∗ Otherwise, if the user answers yes, it should ask Are you really
>   sure you don’t like Java programming?, and repeat.
>
> · If the user keeps saying yes, then the program keeps asking
>
> Are you really really sure you don’t like Java programming?,
>
> then Are you really really really sure you don’t like Java
>   programming?.
>
> And so on, every time printing one more really.
>
> · This should stop when it reaches the point when it prints really 5
>   times.
>
> At that point, if the user still answers yes, it should print Too
>   bad.., and terminate.

I have coded the basic switch case for this however the core answer which includes the repetition of really, should be a for loop or a nested for loop. These loops really confuse me so I need some help with it.

```
package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you like java programming? 'yes' / 'no'");
        String input = scan.next();

        switch (input) {
            case "yes":
            case "Yes":
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you are an advanced intellectual");
                break;
            case "no":
                System.out.println("Are you sure you don't like java programming?");
                String input2 = scan.next();
                switch (input2) {
                    case "no":
                    case "No":
                        System.out.println("Hope you’ll get to like it soon...");
                        break;
                    case "yes":
                    case "Yes":
                        System.out.println("Are you really sure you don’t like Java programming?");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

SAMPLE RUN 1

> Do you like Java programming ? yes or no : no
>
> Are you sure you don ’t like Java programming ? yes or no : yes
>
> Are you really sure you don ’t like Java programming ?  yes or no :
>   yes
>
> Are you really really sure you don ’t like Java programming ?  yes or
>   no : no
>
> Hope you ’ ll get to like it soon ..

SAMPLE RUN 2

> Do you like Java programming ?  yes or no : no
>
> Are you sure you don ’t like Java programming ? yes or no : yes
>
> Are you really sure you don ’t like Java programming ?  yes or no :
>   yes
>
> Are you really really sure you don ’t like Java programming ?  yes or
>   no : yes
>
> Are you really really really sure you don ’t like Java programming ? 
>   yes or no : yes
>
> Are you really really really really sure you don ’t like Java
>   programming ?  yes or no : yes
>
> Are you really really really really really sure you don ’t like Java
>   programming ?  yes or no : yes
>
> Too bad ..

Comment: Four upvotes? There's not even a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic flow of the looping `really` part will be like

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("get user input");

    // test to see if Yes or No (omitted)

    String out = "";
    for (int inner = 0; inner  < i; inner++) {
        out = out + "really, ";
    }
    System.out.println(out);  // you will want to build the proper String
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When user want to give his/her name at run time and takes back name as a output in return.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WriteYourName {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner( System.in );

    String yourName;      // Entered by the user.
    String yourUpperCaseName;  // Change your name to upper case letters.
    
    System.out.print("Please enter your good name: ");
    yourName = stdin.nextLine();
    
    yourUpperCaseName = yourName.toUpperCase();
    
    System.out.println("Hiii, " + yourUpperCaseName + ", How are you buddy?");

}
```

}

Comment: I can't see any relation to the question here. The OP already seems to know how to use a Scanner correctly.